# algorithm to find the three majority elements in an array

Tags: algorithm

Let's say there are three elements in a non-sorted array all of which appear more than one-fourth times of the total number of elements.

What is the most efficient way to find these elements? Both for non-online and online versions of this question.

Thank you!

**Edit**

The non-online version I was referring to is: this array is specified in full. The online version means the array elements are coming one at a time.

I require the space in addition to time complexity to be tight.

disclaimer: THIS IS NOT HOMEWORK! I consider this as research-level question.

Comment: What's a non-online version of a question?

Comment: Make a pass over the array, putting elements into hashmap, where key is an element and value is number of occurrences. Then just take 3 highest elements. This will take O(n) time and same space.

Answer (score 13):

Remember up to three elements, together with counters.

1. remember first element, set count1 = 1
2. scan until you find first different element, increasing count1 for each occurrence of element 1
3. remember second elemt, set count2 = 1
4. scan until you find first element different from elem1 and elem2, incrementing count1 or count2, depending which element you see
5. remember third element, set count3 = 1
6. continue scanning, if the element is one of the remembered, increment its count, if it's none of the remembered, decrement all three counts; if a count drops to 0, forget the element, go to step 1, 3, or 5, depending on how many elements you forget
7. If you have three elements occurring strictly more than one-fourth times the number of elements in the array, you will end up with three remembered elements each with positive count, these are the three majority elements.

Small constant additional space, O(n), no sorting.

Comment: +1. Yes, this is more of less along my line of thought. Does this generalize to `m` elements in an array of length `n`, all of which appear more than `n/k` times?

Comment: @QiangLi It generalises to `m` elements appearing more than `n/(m+1)` times. But the complexity is `O(m*n)` if we regard `m` as variable, so if `m` isn't small, sorting is better.

Comment: This algorithm won't work - try following sequence of elements in array: [1 2 3 4 4 1 5 5 2 6 6 3 1 1 2 2 3 3 3]. Majority elements are 1, 2 and 3, while, but with this algo you will find very different elements.

Comment: @ffriend They appear less than 18/4 times in that example. The algorithm requires that they appear strictly more than n/4 times.

Comment: @ffriend However, in that example, it still finds 2 and 3. After the first three elements, we have (1,1),(2,1),(3,1). Next is 4, decrement and forget all. Continue with [4 1 5 5 2 ...], getting (4,1),(1,1),(5,2) before the 2, decrement, forget 4 & 1. State (5,1) next [6 6 ...], continue to (5,1),(6,2),(3,1), 1, decrement, forget 5&3. Last 1 ~> (6,1),(1,1); 2 2 ~> (6,1),(1,1),(2,2); 3 ~> (2,1); 3 ~> (2,1),(3,1).

Comment: Where did you get this fraction from? Why 18 and why 4? Majority element is the one that occurs more than `n/2` times. I understand 3 majority elements are those which in sum occur same `n/2` times, and this condition is matched in the array.

Comment: @ffriend 18 was due to miscounting (forgot the last 3, so final state would be (2,1),(3,2)), should be 19, as that's the number of elements in your example. For the meaning of majority elements, OP said "three elements in a non-sorted array all of which appear more than one-fourth times of the total number of elements.", so that's the criterion I used.

Comment: The Boyer-Moore Majority Vote Algorithm?

Comment: @st0le Adapted. I had forgotten by whom the original was, thanks.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: ah, now I see, thanks for explanation. I wonder if there's strict mathematical basis for the algorithm. I believe it is possible to reduce problem to the same one majority element problem and thus prove the idea. Anyway, +1 for a good (as I can see now) solution.

Answer (score 2):

create a histogram of the entries, sort it, and take the three largest entries.