# Finding the count of required entries within a list?

Tags: java, algorithm, comparison

Design an algorithm that, given a list of n elements in an array, finds all the elements that appear more than n/3 times in the list. The algorithm should run in linear time ( n >=0 )

You are expected to use comparisons and achieve linear time. No hashing/excessive space/ and don't use standard linear time deterministic selection algorithm?? 
The problem is self-blocking I feel??

Comment: possible duplicate of [An interesting Google interview algorithm I found online that requires linear time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362076/an-interesting-google-interview-algorithm-i-found-online-that-requires-linear-ti)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Take a look at [Boyer and Moore's Linear Time Vote Algorithm](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/moore/best-ideas/mjrty/index.html)

**Steps:**

1. Find median of array using median of medians algorithm in 0(n) time
2. partition using median as pivot element
3. use **moore's voting algo** in each part between
    
   a) median and first element and
   b) median and last element
4. check if median is the required element.

For more detailed algorithms to solve this problem you can refer to [**this**](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/misra/scannedPdf.dir/FindRepeatedElements.pdf) document. Really, this would be very helpful.

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362076/an-interesting-google-interview-algorithm-i-found-online-that-requires-linear-ti) similar post also for more answers.

Comment: really, how does that help? that allows detecting the majority element in the list and even then will only work if the list is organized in a specific way... (as far as I understand it)

Comment: @Nim - no special organization of the list is required.  But I'm not sure that this is a helpful hint either.

Comment: Maybe by modifying this algorithm to increment by 2/decrement by 1? After a first iteration over the list, check whether the selected element has indeed more than 1/3 occurrences. If it is not the case then stop, otherwise output it and then run the **unmodified** algorithm while ignoring the first found element. In 4 iterations in total you should be fine, however the modified algorithm has to be proven… which would probably be difficult as part of an interview!

Comment: Problem description says "don't use standard linear time deterministic selection algorithm", so that would rule out your first step of finding the median. It does seem like a silly restriction though.

Comment: [Chivalryman's Tetris algorithm here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10925983) is a _much_ better way to solve this problem than the Voting algorithm.