# Decimal dominant number in an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Recently i came across this interview question:

You are given n real numbers in an array. A number in the array is called a decimal dominant if it occurs more than n/10 times in the array. Give an O(n) time algorithm to determine if the given array has a decimal dominant.

Now i can think of a few ways to solve this, and any generalisation of this question (i.e. finding any number that appears K times in an array)

One could be to make a hash table in pass 1, and then count the number of occurences in pass 2, which would be O(n), but uses O(n) space as well,

There is one way [using 9 buckets](http://www.solvemyproblem.net/Webed/forum/thread.asp?tid=1318)

But, is there any way we could do it in a constant space?? Any suggestions??

[EDIT] i haven't checked the 9 bucket solution, readers may like to go through n.m.'s comments below

Comment: The one that uses 9 buckets is wrong. A counterexample: {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,0}.

Comment: Perhaps if you modify that solution a bit, it could be saved. Do not show bins with 2 or more in the end, instead go and re-count each item left in the bins.

Comment: i am sorry, i didn't go through the entire code, but the basic idea that i got out of it, i could think of a solution using that ,so i posted that link here... i still won't edit that part, because all i intend is that any reader should get an idea that there is a way like that too
Thanks for your input :)

Comment: For any general k, you require O(n log k) time. The trick is that the dominant element remains same if you delete any k distinct items from the array/list.

Comment: @singhsumit... are you the one from BIT-J, IIT-D???
and could you pleaSe elaborate the solution

Answer (score 9):

I have outlined a way based on the Boyer-Moore majority voting algorithm [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8206433/1011995).

You remember (up to) `(m-1)` elements that have recently been more often seen than the others and associated counts. When a remembered element is seen, its count is increased. When a not-remembered element is seen, if there is a slot free, you remember it and set its count to 1, otherwise you subtract 1 from all counts of the remembered elements. A remembered element whose count goes to 0 is forgotten. Any element occurring with a higher proportion than `1/m` is one of the remembered elements. If you do not know a priori that there are `m-1` elements occurring more than `n/m` times, you need a second pass to count the occurrences of the remembered elements.

**Edit:** After visiting the indicated page, I see it is the exact same solution, except it doesn't account for remembered non-dominants.

> Once this has been finished any count variables with counts greater than 1 have more than 10 instances of themselves in the list.

is not correct, but all decimal dominants will be remembered with a count `>= 1` at the end.
I haven't gone through the code there, so it may contain errors, but the algorithm is correct, except for the missing checking pass.

The proposed counterexample is dealt with correctly if we have the second pass, the state evolves

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1   // coming 9
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   // all forgotten, no slots occupied, coming 10
10 - - - - - - - -
 1 - - - - - - - -  // coming 0
10 0 - - - - - - - 
 1 1 - - - - - - -
```

at the end, there are two slots occupied, 10 and 0 are both remembered with a count of 1. 10 isn't a decimal dominant, but 0 is, and it is the only one, as will be verified by the second checking pass.

Comment: perfect answer. it cant be done in constant space in O(N) time.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int[] KthDominants(int[] arr, int kth)
    {
        var data = new Dominants(arr.Length, kth);
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            data.Push(arr[i]);
        }
        return data.ToArray();
    }
```

The Dominants class stores kth-1 counters in a Dictionary. It uses System.Linq to work with collections.

```
public class Dominants
{
    int _size;
    int _kth;
    int _grade;
    Dictionary<int, int> _counters;

    public Dominants(int size, int kth)
    {
        _size = size;
        _kth = kth;
        _counters = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    }

    public void Push(int key)
    {
        if (_counters.ContainsKey(key))
            _counters[key]++;
        else
        {
            // The trick is that the dominant element remains same 
            // if you delete any k distinct items from the array.
            if (_counters.Count < _kth)
                _counters.Add(key, 1);
            else
            {
                foreach (var i in _counters.Keys.ToArray())
                {
                    if (_counters[i] > 1)
                        _counters[i]--;
                    else
                        _counters.Remove(i);
                }
                _grade++;
            }
        }
    }

    public int[] ToArray()
    {
        var cnt = _size / _kth - (_grade + 1);
        return _counters
            .Where(i => i.Value > cnt)
            .Select(i => i.Key)
            .ToArray();
    }
}
```

[github](https://github.com/dlarionov/algorithms/tree/master/Part%20I/IQ/06%20-%20Quicksort/Decimal%20dominants)

Answer (score 1):

you may use *3-way-partition* *quick-select* to find the (n/10)th largest element of the array, and then check whether it's decimal-dominant; if not, recur in the right sub-array.

this can be done in-place and within linear expectation time, so not strictly constant space.

Comment: What's the terminating condition? What to look for in the right subarray? Your answer is not specific.

Answer (score 1):

Using 3-way qSort Java implementation printing

```
public class DecimalDominants {
    public static void sort(Comparable[] arr) {
        sort(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);
    }

    private static void sort(Comparable[] arr, int lo, int hi) {
        if (lo >= hi) return;
        int lt = lo, gt = hi;
        Comparable v = arr[lo];
        int i = lo;
        while (i <= gt) {
            int cmp = arr[i].compareTo(v);
            if (cmp < 0) swap(arr, lt++, i++);
            else if (cmp > 0) swap(arr, i, gt--);
            else i++;
        }
        int times = gt - lt + 1;
        if (times > arr.length / 10) System.out.printf("%s repeats %d times\n", v, times);
        sort(arr, lo, lt - 1);
        sort(arr, gt + 1, hi);
    }

    private static void swap(Comparable[] arr, int i, int j) {
        Comparable swap = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = swap;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] arr = {1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 3, 2, 4, 5, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 3, 2, 5};
        System.out.println("print numbers which repeat more then " + arr.length / 10);
        sort(arr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. do a loop and store/add the value in the array of real numbers int[].
2. do another loop that divides the array list values  by 10 if its greater than 1 its a decimal dominant.

Comment: yeah, but how is that any different from the hash table approach??
i was actually looking for a solution that uses constant space

Answer (score 0):

Three way sorting with linear time complexity and constant space complexity.
Worst case this recursive call will be made 10 times

```
def three_way_partition(arr, start, end, dominants):
    if (end - start + 1) >= int(len(arr)/10):
        lt = start
        gt = end
        i = lt
        while True:
            if arr[i] < arr[lt]:
                arr[lt], arr[i] = arr[i], arr[lt]
                i += 1
                lt += 1
            elif arr[i] > arr[lt]:
                arr[gt], arr[i] = arr[i], arr[gt]
                gt -= 1
            else:
                i += 1
            if i > gt:
                break
        if gt - lt + 1 > int(len(arr)/10):
            dominants.append(arr[lt])
        three_way_partition(arr, start, lt-1, dominants)
        three_way_partition(arr, gt + 1, end,  dominants)


def decimal_dominants(arr):
    dominants = []
    three_way_partition(arr, 0, len(arr)-1, dominants)
    return dominants
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided this question with Dijkstra's approach to solve DNF problem.
Please see my emplementation below. May be it will be interest and useful to somebody. Very similar to @pushkin code.

```
public void dCount(Comparable[] arr) {
    dCount(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);
}
private void dCount(Comparable[] arr, int lo, int hi) {
    if (lo >= hi) return;
    int curr = lo;
    int lt = lo;
    int rt = hi;
    Comparable pivot = arr[lo];

    while (curr <= rt) { // 3-way qSort main cycle
        if (less(arr[curr], pivot))
            swap(arr, curr++, lt++);
        else if (less(pivot, arr[curr]))
            swap(arr, curr, rt--);
        else curr++;
    }
    int count = curr - lt;
    if (count > arr.length / 10) { // you can change count value if it needs (n / 3, n / 2... just change 10 to your number)           
        System.out.printf("%s repeats %d times\n", arr[lt], count);
    }
    dCount(arr, lo, lt -1); // recur call for the left side from the pivot equal range
    dCount(arr, rt + 1, hi); // recur call for the right side from the pivot equal range
}
private static boolean less(Comparable a, Comparable b) {
    return a.compareTo(b) < 0;
}
private static void swap(Comparable[] arr, int i, int j) {
    Comparable swap = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = swap;
}
```